# Update scheduling policy configuration

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using Kubernetes on Google Container Engine.

As [this article](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/scheduler.html) says, Kubernetes' scheduling policy can be configured using JSON files.

However, I can't find out how to apply its configuration to the cluster.  There are no such subcommands as updating policy in `kubectl`.

Do I have to use another command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the command-line flag `--policy-config-file` to the scheduler. It's cluster config parameter.
Doc: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/devel/scheduler.md

Probably you can't setup it on Google Container Engine. Google Container Engine = preconfigured stable Kubernetes cluster. Build your own Kubernetes cluster and then you can set up what do you need.

Comment: How can I achieve it on Google Container Engine?

Answer (score 2):

Jan is correct -- this isn't configurable on Google Container Engine. With the upcoming Kubernetes 1.2 release you will be able to run a custom scheduler in your cluster, which you will be able to configure however you'd like.